# D2: empty string in a conditional statement

Tags: d

In the following code, why does 2 give output but not 3? The removechars statement returns a string with length 0

```
import std.stdio, std.string;

void main() {
    string str = null;
    if (str) writeln(1); // no

    str = "";
    if (str) writeln(2); // yes

    if (",&%$".removechars(r"^a-z"))  writeln(3); // no
}
```

Edit: Ok, it may return null, but I'm still a bit puzzled because all of these print true

```
writeln(",&%$".removechars(r"^a-z") == "");
writeln(",&%$".removechars(r"^a-z") == null);
writeln(",&%$".removechars(r"^a-z").length == 0);
```

Edit 2: This also prints true, but put either of them in a conditional and you get a different result

```
writeln("" == null);
```

Edit 3: Alright, I understand that I cannot test for an empty string the way I did. What led to this question is the following situation. I want to remove chars from a word, but don't want to store an empty string:

```
if (auto w = word.removechars(r"^a-z"))
    wordcount[w]++;
```

This works when I try it, but that must be because removechars is returning null rather than ""

Comment: I think the `if(array)` is rewritten as `if(array.ptr!=null)` and not `if(array.length!=0)` I'm  not sure though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`removeChars`](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/d1d81245ea26603980ca15fd3aa24eef00289123/std/string.d#L2367) will return `null` when no characters match.

(This happens because `.dup` of an empty string will always be `null`.)

Comment: Somewhat related question from me: Is a `null` array supposed to be logically different from an empty array in D?

Comment: By empty I meant with a length of zero. `if(s)` checks if `s` is `null`, so yes. You can check either case explicitly by using `if(s is null)` or `if(s.length==0)`.

Answer (score 2):

D arrays, or slices if you prefer, are interesting beasts.

In D an empty array is equal to null, or more appropriately a null array is equal to an empty array, this is why assert("" == null) or assert([] == null). However when using just if(str) you're asking if there is a string here, and for null there isn't an array. It is equivalent to an empty array, but one does not exist.

The proper way to check if something is null: assert(str is null). I'm not sure which is best for converting a string to a bool, but really there can't be a perfect solution because string isn't a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Always use **is** and **!is** (is not) to compare with null. If you want to check if a string is empty check against its length property:

```
string str;
assert(str is null);    // str is null
assert(!str);           // str is null

str = "";
assert(str !is null);   // no longer null
assert(str);            // no longer null

assert(!str.length);    // but it's zero length
```

Comment: I thought `null` arrays and empty arrays are treated equivalently in D, aren't they?

Comment: No they are not equivalent. IIRC there was a long thread on the newsgroup about if the distinction between no-contents and and no-array was worth allowing and the conclusion was that it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!str.length) { 
//dosomething ... 
}
```

Comment: This answer has no value to the question he is asking. I actually don't even know what this is is an appropriate answer to.